# JAXB: why are defined namespace prefixes not used in generated xml document?

Tags: jaxb, xml-namespaces, prefix, moxy

Hi I have generated from an xml schema file (mets.xsd) java classes with xic compiler. This xsd file uses some other namespaces (premis.xsd, ead.xsd ...). To use namespace prefixes I added some annotations to package-info.java file as follows:

```
@XmlSchema(
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    location="http://www.loc.gov/mets/mets.xsd",
    namespace="http://www.loc.gov/METS/",
    xmlns=
    {
            @XmlNs(prefix="METS",   namespaceURI="http://www.loc.gov/mets/"),
            @XmlNs(prefix="EAD",    namespaceURI="http://www.loc.gov/ead/"),
            @XmlNs(prefix="PREMIS", namespaceURI="http://www.loc.gov/premis/v2/"),
            @XmlNs(prefix="xlink",  namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"),
            @XmlNs(prefix="OAI_DC", namespaceURI="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/"),
            @XmlNs(prefix="DC",     namespaceURI="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")
    }
)
package ch.eugster.herakles.sip.matterhorn.mets;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

When I Marshall the java object to xml, I get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:mets xmlns:METS="http://www.loc.gov/mets/" xmlns:EAD="http://www.loc.gov/ead/" xmlns:PREMIS="http://www.loc.gov/premis/v2/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:OAI_DC="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xmlns:DC="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.loc.gov/METS/" PROFILE="http://www.docuteam.ch/xmlns/sip-profile.xml">
   <ns1:amdSec/>
   <ns1:fileSec>
      <ns1:fileGrp/>
   </ns1:fileSec>
   <ns1:structMap>
      <ns1:div TYPE="rootfolder" ORDER="1" LABEL="RootFolder_Temp"/>
   </ns1:structMap>
</ns1:mets>
```

As you see the prefixes are defined correctly but they are not used in the document. Has anyone an idea, what could cause this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, Even I am facing the same problem actually. The provided `prefix` is no used during the creation of `QName`. It always uses the default namespace prefix such as `ns0,ns1, etc`. I am also using the `Moxy`. Have you found the answer to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Even I was facing the same issue (Even after providing the `custom prefix` to my `QName` i was getting the default namespace prefix such as `ns0,ns1,etc`) so I tried a lot of things and finally was able to get it so posting the same here so it can be helpful to you and maybe someone else in the future. You can find [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67553941/creation-of-qname-takes-default-namesapce-prefix-rather-than-the-provided-parame)

1. Remove the `package-info.java` and all of its content (if you have added while trying something).
2. Since you are using the `Moxy` you can create a `Map` with all of the required `NamespcaeURI and Prefix`. Something like this:

```
Map<String, String> urisToPrefixes = new HashMap<String, String>();
urisToPrefixes.put("http://www.loc.gov/mets/", "METS");
urisToPrefixes.put("http://www.loc.gov/ead/", "EAD"); 
urisToPrefixes.put("http://www.loc.gov/premis/v2/", "PREMIS");
```

3. While using the `Marshalling` approach add the `property` and send this `Map` as a parameter:

```
    marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER, urisToPrefixes);
```

This will ensure that whenever a `Namespace` is encountered it would check for the respective `prefix` and add it to the `XML header` so in this was it would replace all the default prefix `ns0,ns1 etc` to corresponding `prefix` from the map.

Complete sample code:

```
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] { TestObject.class, SubObject.class });
Map<String, String> urisToPrefixes = new HashMap<String, String>();
urisToPrefixes.put("http://www.loc.gov/mets/", "METS");
urisToPrefixes.put("http://www.loc.gov/ead/", "EAD"); urisToPrefixes.put("http://www.loc.gov/premis/v2/", "PREMIS");
Marshaller m = ctx.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER, prefixesToUris);
```

If you would like to more about this and another approach find the [documentation here:](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.4.0/JAXB_RI_Extensions/Namespace_Prefix_Mapper)