# Creation of QName takes default namesapce prefix rather than the provided parameter

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy, qnames

I am using the `JaxB Marshalling` to create the `XML`. My XML I have few custom fields which I am creating using the `JAXB XmlAdapter` option. The custom fields are created using the `JAXBElement`, in which `QName` is one of the parameters.

As per the `QName` documentation it takes 3 parameters `NamespaceURI`, `LocalPart` and `Prefix`. I am passing all these parameters. But for some reason, the created `XML` takes the default namespace prefix `ns0, ns1, ns2` etc rather than the provided one in the `QName` creation parameter.

Everything is working as expected without any issue. I just want to know how can I make the `QName` take up the `custom prefix` value that I am passing as a parameter rather than the `default namespace prefix` it's adding automatically. I am aware that if I do not pass the `prefix` value then it would take the `default namespace prefix` but in my case, even after passing the `custom prefix` value, it's assigning the `default namespaces prefix` to `XML` which I want to avoid. I tried many things but still, nothing worked out.

Note: I am not using the `javax Jaxb` libraray rather than that I am using the `EclipseLink  Moxy` which is based on `Jaxb` implementation.

Currently, the created XML would look something like this: (Please note that these do not root elements or XML header rather these are chunks taken from a certain part of the XML).

```
   <ns0:MainField xmlns:ns0="https://google.com?xsd=google.xsd">
      <ns1:SubField1 xmlns:ns1="https://fb.com?xsd=fb.xsd">
         <ns2:Field1 xmlns:ns2="https://fb.com?xsd=fb.xsd">Value1</ns2:Field1>
      </ns1:SubField1>
      <ns3:SubField3 xmlns:ns3="https://google.com?xsd=google.xsd">SubValue3</ns3:SubField3>
   </ns0:MainField>
   <ns4:MainField2 xmlns:ns4="https://google.com?xsd=google.xsd">MainValue2</ns4:MainField2>
```

Where as I am expecting it to look something like this based on the values I have provided to the `QName` field:

```
   <google:MainField xmlns:google="https://google.com?xsd=google.xsd">
      <fb:SubField1 xmlns:fb="https://fb.com?xsd=fb.xsd">
         <fb:Field1 xmlns:fb="https://fb.com?xsd=fb.xsd">Value1</fb:Field1>
      </fb:SubField1>
      <google:SubField3 xmlns:google="https://google.com?xsd=google.xsd">SubValue3</google:SubField3>
   </google:MainField>
   <google:MainField2 xmlns:google="https://google.com?xsd=google.xsd">MainValue2</google:MainField2>
```

Following is my `Java` class which is creating the `QName`. I have a `Map<String, Object>` based on the type of value it's creating the `QName`. Everything is working as expected except the part of the `QName namespace prefix`.

```
import io.openepcis.service.jaxb.DefaultJsonSchemaNamespaceURIResolver;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.NotImplementedException;


public class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MapWrapper, Map<String, Object>> {

  DefaultJsonSchemaNamespaceURIResolver uriResolver = new DefaultJsonSchemaNamespaceURIResolver();

  @Override
  public Map<String, Object> unmarshal(MapWrapper valueType) throws Exception {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  @Override
  public MapWrapper marshal(Map<String, Object> extensions) throws Exception {
    if (extensions == null) {
      return null;
    }

    MapWrapper wrapper = new MapWrapper();

    List elements = new ArrayList();

    //Loop through the Extensions MAP
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> property : extensions.entrySet()) {
    

        final Optional<String> xmlNamespace = uriResolver.namespaceURIFromSchema(extension.getKey());
        
        String namespaceURI = xmlNamespace.get();
        String localPart = getLocalPart(property.getKey());
        String prefix = getPrefix(property.getKey());
        String label = getCleanLabel(property.getKey());
        System.out.println(" namespaceURI : " + namespaceURI + " localPart : " + localPart + " prefix : " + prefix);
        
        //If the Value type is MAP then recurse through the loop
        if (property.getValue() instanceof Map) {
        elements.add(new JAXBElement<MapWrapper>(new QName(namespaceURI, localPart, prefix), MapWrapper.class, marshal((Map) property.getValue())));
        } else if (property.getValue() instanceof String) {
        // If the Value type is String then directly create JAXBElement
        elements.add(new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(namespaceURI, localPart, prefix), String.class, property.getValue().toString()));
        }
        }
        wrapper.elements = elements;
        return wrapper;
    }
  
    // Formats the complete Label for the XML tag
    public static String getCleanLabel(String label) {
        label = label.replaceAll("[()]", "").replaceAll("[^\\w\\s]", "_").replaceAll(" ", "_");
        return label;
    }
    
    //Formats the LocalPart of the XML Tag (after ":")
    public static String getLocalPart(String localPart) {
        localPart = localPart.substring(localPart.indexOf(":") + 1);
        return localPart;
    }
    
    //Formats the Prefix of the XML Tag (before ":")
    public static String getPrefix(String prefix) {
        prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.indexOf(":"));
        return prefix;
    }
}

class MapWrapper {
  @XmlAnyElement
  List elements;
}


class DefaultJsonSchemaNamespaceURIResolver{
    private static Map<String, String> xmlNamespaces = new HashMap<String, String>();
    
    static {
        xmlNamespaces.put("google", "https://google.com");
        xmlNamespaces.put("fb", "https://fb.com");
        xmlNamespaces.put("insta", "https://instagram.com");
    }
    
    public Optional<String> namespaceURIFromSchema(String schemaURI) {
        if (xmlNamespaces.containsKey(schemaURI)) {
          return Optional.of(xmlNamespaces.get(schemaURI));
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Following are the dependencies I am using in my `Maven pom.xml`:

```
    <!-- JAXB Annotations Dependencies START -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JAXB Annotations Dependencies END -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of things and referring to many things I was able to get it. I am using the `Moxy` dependency instead of `Jaxb` as it provides various additional benefits on top of the existing features in `Jaxb`. Posting this answer as it can be helpful to someone in the future:

1. Remove the `package-info.java` and all of its content (if you have added it while trying something because I see a lot of answers here are based on it).
2. Since you are using the `Moxy` you can create a Map with all of the required `NamespcaeURI` and `Prefix`. Something like this:

```
    Map<String, String> urisToPrefixes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    urisToPrefixes.put("http://www.root.com", "rootNS");
    urisToPrefixes.put("http://sub.root.com", "subNS");
```

3. While using the Marshalling approach add the property and send this Map as a parameter:

```
marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER, urisToPrefixes);
```

This will ensure that whenever a `Namespace` is encountered it would check for the respective `prefix` and add it to the XML header so in this way it would replace all the default prefix ns0,ns1, etc to the corresponding prefix from the map.

```
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] { TestObject.class, SubObject.class });
 
Map<String, String> urisToPrefixes = new HashMap<String, String>();
urisToPrefixes.put("http://www.root.com", "rootNS");
urisToPrefixes.put("http://sub.root.com", "subNS");        
 
Marshaller m = ctx.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER, prefixesToUris);
```

If you would like to read more about it then follow the [official documentation here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.4.0/JAXB_RI_Extensions/Namespace_Prefix_Mapper).